# Is it possible to cast a managed bytes-array to native struct without pin_ptr, so not to bug the GC too much?

Tags: c++-cli

It is possible to cast a managed `array<Byte>^` to some non-managed `struct` only using `pin_ptr`, AFAIK, like:

```
void Example(array<Byte>^ bfr) {
    pin_ptr<Byte> ptr = &bfr[0];
    auto data = reinterpret_cast<NonManagedStruct*>(ptr);
    data->Header = 7;
    data->Length = sizeof(data);
    data->CRC = CalculateCRC(data);
}
```

However, is with `interior_ptr` in any way?

I'd rather work on managed data the low-level-way (using `union`s, `struct`-bit-fields, and so on), without pinning data - I could be holding this data for quite a long time and don't want to harass the `GC`.

#### Clarification:

I do not want to copy managed-data to native and back (so the `Marshaling` way is not an option here...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely won't harass the GC with `pin_ptr` - it's pretty lightweight unlike `GCHandle`.

`GCHandle::Alloc(someObject, GCHandleType::Pinned)` will actually register the object as being pinned in the GC. This lets you pin an object for extended periods of time and across function calls, but the GC has to track that object.

On the other hand, `pin_ptr` gets translated to a pinned local in IL code. The GC isn't notified about it, but it will get to see that the object is pinned *only* during a collection. That is, it will notice it's pinned status when looking for object references on the stack.

---

If you *really* want to, you can access stack memory in the following way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind::Explicit, Size = 256)]
public value struct ManagedStruct
{
};

struct NativeStruct
{
    char data[256];
};

static void DoSomething()
{
    ManagedStruct managed;
    auto nativePtr = reinterpret_cast<NativeStruct*>(&managed);
    nativePtr->data[42] = 42;
}
```

There's no pinning at all here, but this is only due to the fact that the managed struct is stored on the stack, and therefore is *not relocatable* in the first place.

It's a convoluted example, because you could just write:

```
static void DoSomething()
{
    NativeStruct native;
    native.data[42] = 42;
}
```

...and the compiler would perform a similar trick under the covers for you.

Comment: From your answer I take it as it's not possible in any way to use `interior_ptr` for native-casting, right? so how can I treat certain byte-array as a native `struct`? I just can't without pinning it?

Comment: Indeed, you can't do that for good reason: if a managed object isn't pinned it can be relocated by the GC, and you don't want that to happen while you're using it in native code. See my edit for an actual example without pinning, but it won't be really relevant I'm afraid.

Comment: Alas, endless marshaling is obligatory... that's why I look forward to the days when GC lives with C++ in harmony, or a native language with GC seizes control (like `D`). Or at least `C#` start playing nicely with bits...

Comment: No need to marshal... if you pin :-) Really, there's no need to worry about pinning unless you can prove by profiling it has a serious impact (and I'm willing to bet your managed/native transition thunks will have a much greater impact on performance than pinning).